# cURL error 61: Error while processing content unencoding: incorrect header check (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: curl, here-api

We encountered a problem. We didn’t changed anything in the project.(laravel v8.x) We turned a backup version from 2mths before to check if the problem is on our side.
Request https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apikey=KEY&q=Nysa sent by Postman/browser was working with every „q” parameter. But since yesterday the problem occured: : cURL error 61: Error while processing content unencoding: incorrect header check (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) ) for https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apikey=KEY&q=Krak%C3%B3w for parameter q=Kraków. On the other hand q=Lesko is working without problems, but q=Nysa is not working.
We Wonder why some of q are working and some are not.
Is it a global problem on Here level?
Best regards,

Comment: Curl could not understand the response.  Capture it with wireshark to figure out what it's sending that is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the here maps api is broken, because i receive the same error via the Laravel Http client since Feb 17, 2022 12:51:50 PM UTC.

When firing the here maps autocomplete api (via insomnia) directly with the same request, inconsistent results are returned:
first request works, the following ones fail with the following error messsage *"Error: Unrecognized or bad HTTP Content or Transfer-Encoding"*.

**UPDATE:**

After more investigation, i realized that all requests work perfectly fine with postman and curl, since they automatically set the `"Accept-Encoding: gzip"` header in the request.

Insomnia does not seem to do it. https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/issues/1025
https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/issues/2047

When adding the header to the insomnia requests the endpoint seems to return consistently a successful response.

This seems to be also true for the Http Client of laravel v8.x. if you add `"Accept-Encoding: gzip"`, the requests work fine again.

Comment: Saved my day. Been debugging the same.